# Connect to AWS EC2 via SSH from GitLab Runner without allowing access from anywhere

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I do have a deploy pipeline on GitLab to deploy an node.js application to an AWS EC2 instance. Everything works fine, because i setup the EC2 security group to be accessible via SSH from anywhere. When i disable the "access from anywhere" rule, GitLab is obviously not able to ssh into the ec2 instance anymore.

But i don't want to have an completely open security group. Is there any solution to this without setting up an GitLab Runner on AWS itself?

Comment: Looks like you can just whitelist gitlab's IP range? https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/gitlab_com/

Comment: nice find, didn't know that, however i tried adding both CIDR blocks, but still get a connection timeout.

Comment: Yeah, I re read that: `For outgoing connections from CI/CD runners, we are not providing static IP addresses. All GitLab.com shared runners are deployed into Google Cloud Platform (GCP). Any IP-based firewall can be configured by looking up all IP address ranges or CIDR blocks for GCP` --- I wouldn't do that

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways you can do this.

1. You can deploy your application using an AWS service like AWS CodePipeline. GitLab uploads artifacts to AWS CodePipeline then AWS CodePipelines updates your EC2 instance on your behalf from inside AWS. There are many ways you can orchestrate this, you don't have to use CodePipeline in particular.
2. You can access the EC2 instance using Systems Manager (Session manager)

## Systems Manager

Use AWS Systems Manager (SSM session manager) to access systems. You'll need to configure your EC2 instance with Systems Manager and install client libraries for session manager.

See [setting up session manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-getting-started.html) and [working with session manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-working-with.html).

Basically the way this works is that instead of talking to the EC2 instance directly, you talk to the AWS systems manager service, which tunnels your connection to the ssm agent on the EC2 instance for you (after authenticating/authorizing your access). Your instance can be in a private subnet with no internet access and this will still work as long as you have setup the system and IAM permissions correctly.

The steps you would take in your CI pipeline (after your instance and IAM role and SSH keys are setup) might look like this:

```
ssh_to_ec2:
  image: python:3.9-slim
  script: |
    # install prerequisite software
    apt update && apt install -y --no-install-recommends curl ssh
    pip install awscli
    curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/session-manager-downloads/plugin/latest/linux_64bit/session-manager-plugin.rpm" -o "session-manager-plugin.rpm"
    dpkg -i session-manager-plugin.deb
    # now you can run commands over ssh, copy files, etc.

    # copy files using scp
    scp -i path/to/my-key-pair.pem ./dist/myapp ec2-user@instance-id:/path/to/server/myapp
    
    # run commands with ssh
    ssh -i path/to/my-key-pair.pem ec2-user@instance-id 'sudo systemctl reload apache2' # or whatever
```

For added security, you can also use temporary SSH keys uploaded using ec2 instance connect. You can even use instances like this as SSH tunnels, too.

```sh
# generate and upload a temporary key for the OS user
ssh-keygen -b 4096 -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/tempkey -q -N ""
aws ec2-instance-connect send-ssh-public-key --instance-id <YOUR-instance-id> --availability-zone <YOUR-instance-availability-zone> --instance-os-user ssm-user --ssh-public-key file://~/.ssh/tempkey.pub

# use the key to open an SSH tunnel to somewhere else in the AWS network.

ssh -i ~/.ssh/tempkey -N -f -M -S ./tunnel.sock \
    -L {local_port}:{remote_host}:{remote_port} ssm-user@{instance_id} \ 
    -o "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" \
    -o ProxyCommand="aws ssm start-session --target %h --document-name AWS-StartSSHSession --parameters portNumber=%p" && read -rsn1 -p "Session active." &
# contact the remote host/port via the EC2 instance tunnel
curl localhost:{localport}
```

This can be useful, for example, for communicating with an RDS database in a private subnet.